# Re-using Apache Flink's ExecutionEnvironment for batch processing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm considering using Apache Flink in a long running application to perform joins on small batches of data using the coGroup operator. Is it possible to re-use an ExecutionEnvironment and repeatedly call collect() on it to achieve this? If it's possible, is the ExecutionEnvironment safe to call from different threads, or would I have to maintain a ThreadLocal?

Thanks!